# Android - How to run multiple periodic handlers, simultaneously

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a screen with multiple progressbars. I'm trying to run them all periodically, at the same time.

I originally did this like so (handler runs on the UI thread):

```
// Timers and Handlers for each of the 45 progressbars on screen. 
private Timer[] timer = new Timer[45];
private Handler[] handler = new Handler[45];
private boolean endTimers = false; 
private Handler handlerHolder;
private int idx; 
private void initTimers(){
    for(int i=0;i<timer.length;i++){
        idx = i;
        handlerHolder = handler[i] 
        timer[i] = new Timer();
        handler[i] = new Handler();
        final int finalI = i;
        timer[i].scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler[finalI].post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (endTimers){
                            return;
                        }
                        timerEvent(finalI);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 100);
    }
}
```

This works, however, I'm finding that the progressbars glitch sometimes, and I read that TimerTasks have lots of issues with android. I tried to rewrite my code with handlers only, but it would just result in an infinite loop on the first index in the for loop.

**My Attempt**

```
private Runnable actionRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (endTimers){
            return;
        }
        timerEvent(idx);
        handlerHolder.postDelayed(actionRunnable, 100);
    }
};
```

Then instead of the `timer[i].scheduleAtFixedRate` block above, I write

```
handler[i].postDelayed(actionRunnable, 100);
```

I understand why this creates an infinite loop ... but I'm not sure what I should do keep this handler running, but continue with the for-loop, like the the original way I did it.

I'd like for all my handlers in handlerArray to run periodically, all at the same time. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Handlers are meant for communicating between threads, so it makes no sense to write code with handlers only but no additional threads.

Comment: Please give a [mcve].  You must provide all relevant variable declarations and initialization.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added more code and details. Let me know if my question is clearer. Thanks!

Comment: All of the handlers run on the same thread. The only thing that runs on the time thread is the call to post(). But the runabble which is posted runs on the handlers thread. You need to move any long-running code to the time threads.

Answer (score 0):

`Handler.post()` executes the given Runnable on the thread which created the Handler. You are probably creating all the Handlers on the UI thread. This is no different than running the code directly. You need to create threads to the time consuming tasks. You can either do this directly with Threads or you can extend AsyncTask. The later is preferable.

Comment: It is different! They run asynchronously!

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike What is "they"? What is running asynchronously? The `Runnable`s? Are you sure? I suggest you read more about `Handler` and how its `post()` method works.

Comment: Yes. I am sure.  `post`ed `Runnables` run asynchronously on the `Handler`'s thread.  This is not the same as running code "directly"/synchronously.

Comment: If the `Runnable`s all run on the same thread, they are **not** asynchronous. To run them asyncronously, you need to create new threads for each one.

Comment: You are correct that it is run on the same thread.  You are not correct that it is not asynchronous.  Perhaps this is just a misunderstanding of the word "asynchronous", which just means "out of order".  Things posted to a `Handler` are queued for future execution, asynchronously.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Yes, I was using the term "asynchronous" when "concurrent" would more accurately match what I mean.

Comment: Got it!  That explains the misunderstanding!